# Why does VS code C++ extension say "parsing paused"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS code is taking forever to "discover files" and parse them with the C++ extension (like days).  As part of this frustration, it will say "parsing paused" sometimes when I hover over the database icon at the lower right.  Clicking on it and selecting "resume parsing" most often has no effect.  What does this mean?